# conditional formatting checking for a match in two different columns

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements, match, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a conditional formatting rule that says:
IF A1 MATCHES a date in row B or C AND is greater than D1
I can do this with two conditional rules:

```
=AND(match(A1, $B:$B,0),A1>=$D$1)
=AND(match(A1, $C:$C,0),A1>=$D$1)
```

but it doesnt work when I try to check both match statements in one conditon:

```
=AND(OR(match(A1, $B:$B,0),match(A1, $C:$C,0)),A1>=$D$1)
```

and neither does

```
=AND(match(A1, $B:$C,0),A1>=$D$1)
```

I need to do this a lot and writing them all seperately will take about a hundred CF's so was wondering if anyone knows a way of checking all these conditions in one?

**EDIT:**

I've made a simple example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UqIZuJQviIgk4mjtBj8yH0_FFJavCrhcRdMB4kV8h04/edit?usp=sharing
In this example, A2 will only go green if these conditions are all true:

```
=AND(match(A2, $B2:$B,0),A2>=$D$2,A2<$E$2)
A2 also appears in column B
A2 is after D2
A2 is before E2
```

What I want is one conditional statement that checks these conditions but rather than just seeing if the date matches a date in column B, see if the date matches a date in column B OR column C.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? By `greater than` in terms of a date, I assume you mean `after`?

Comment: @iansedano sample data provided, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=MATCH($A$2, {$B$2:$B; $C$2:$C}, 0)*($A$2>=$D$2)*($A$2<$E$2)
```

Comment: @JoeW can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: copy shared (works with a match in B column but not C column)

Answer (score 1):

#### How to combine simple logical comparison and multiple `MATCH` instances

```
=AND(
    OR(
        IFERROR(MATCH(A2,$B2:$B,0), FALSE),
        IFERROR(MATCH(A2,$C2:$C,0), FALSE)
    ),
    A2>=$D$2,
    A2<$E$2
)
```

If `MATCH` doesn't find anything, then it returns an error. So you need to wrap it in an `IFERROR` or similar. Omitting it works for one, but when you wrap them together in an `OR` it looks like it will always end up returning `FALSE` because it will always return an ERROR.

#### Reference

- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)
- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)